# AWS API Gateway Method Response in CloudFormation

Tags: aws-api-gateway, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to set up my API Gateway so it has this simple method response:

[image: Method Response]

[image: Method Response Details]

And I am using CloudFormation and I keep running into errors. I believe this is pretty simple but I am stuck after spending hours reading docs. Here is my method resource (in YAML):

```
MyMethod:
Type: "AWS::ApiGateway::Method"
Properties:
  AuthorizationType: "NONE"
  HttpMethod: "GET"
  Integration:
    Type: AWS
    Credentials: !GetAtt MyRole.Arn
    IntegrationHttpMethod: "POST"
    Uri:
      Fn::Join: [ "", [ "arn:aws:apigateway:", Ref: "AWS::Region", ":states:action/SendTaskSuccess" ] ]
    PassthroughBehavior: WHEN_NO_TEMPLATES
    RequestTemplates:
      application/json: |
        {
           "output": "\"Approve link was clicked.\"",
           "taskToken": "$input.params('taskToken')"
        }
    IntegrationResponses:
      - StatusCode: 200
        ResponseTemplates: {"application/json": "$input.json('$.body')"}
   RequestParameters:
    method.request.querystring.taskToken: false
  OperationName: succeed
  ResourceId: !Ref MyResource
  RestApiId: !Ref MyApi
```

Do I need a MethodResponse property?

Answer (score 13):

Ok it looks like I just had to add this:

```
MethodResponses:
    - StatusCode: 200
      ResponseModels: { "application/json": "Empty" }
```

Comment: any idea how can we map the response also instead of 'Empty'

Comment: @Jana I think you can add key-value pairs that refer to a model resource. I didn't get it working perfectly before moving on, but it seems like that's how it's done. Here's the docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigateway-model.html

Answer (score -1):

```
  ApiPATCH:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Method
    Properties:
      RestApiId: APIGateway
      ResourceId: ProxyResourceROOT
      HttpMethod: PATCH  
      AuthorizationType: NONE
       Integration:
        Type: AWS
        IntegrationHttpMethod: POST
        Uri: !Join 
          - ''
          - - 'arn:aws:apigateway:'
            - !Ref 'AWS::Region'
            - ':lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/'
            - !GetAtt 
              - LambdaFunction
              - Arn
            - /invocations
        IntegrationResponses:
          - StatusCode: 200
      MethodResponses:
        - StatusCode: 200
          ResponseModels:
            application/json: 'Empty'
```

Answer (score -4):

Yes that's right. You need to add the following:

MethodResponses:

- StatusCode: 200

  ResponseModels:

  ```
    application/json: 'Empty'
  ```